# Undo a git pull --rebase, log doesn't show commits?

Tags: git, version-control

I'm pretty new to git so not sure how to fix the current problem I find myself in.  I was told to do a

```
git pull --rebase
git push
```

To merge my local commits to the ones on the server.  Now however, all my commits and code changes are gone and I have no clue how to get them back.  If I do a

```
git log
```

it shows none of my local commits.  How do I advance from here?  Ideally I would like my commits to be merged with the servers, but if I could get back to the stage before the --rebase then I would be happy also.

A git reflog does show some of the commits I had made, here is an expert.

[image]

The commit "Adding missing jars" is the last I performed locally.

Comment: Follow-up question: Are you working directly in Dropbox? Not sure if that is a good idea. See this link for setting up a bare repo for Dropbox: https://freshmob.com.au/using-dropbox-as-a-git-repository/

Comment: Can you show the log before `git pull --rebase` and after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you do a reset to origin/master first (see HEAD@{2} in your reflog)? That will make you lose your local changes.

Anyway, you can try again. To go back to where you were do this:

```
git reset --hard HEAD@{3}
```

And then you can try your git pull with rebase again.

If this feels a bit unsafe, you can always make a backup branch before doing the git pull.

```
git branch backup
```

Comment: "reset to origin/master first (see HEAD@{2})", this is the first step of `git pull --rebase`. I believe it is not done by OP.

Comment: I was wondering about that. I checked the reflog of one of my repos and couldn't see any resets during rebases but I usually fetch and then rebase.